# How to handle Java "jobs" synchronously?

Tags: java, concurrency, synchronization

We have a set of actions or "Jobs" which we'd like to happen one at a time (not concurrently).  Ie: Job A can't happen while B is happening, and you can't have two C jobs running at the same time.

In the event that a thread attempts to run a job concurrently they should get an error.  We shouldn't just queue up the request.

Some jobs happen asynchronously where the user makes request, we return a status message and id, and then process job asynchronously on server.

We're looking for advice on how to handle this scenario.

One option is to [lock on a shared object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1777542/how-to-prevent-concurrency-in-web-service-api/1777716#1777716):

```
public class Global {
  public static final Object lock = new Object();
}

public class JobA {
    public void go() {
        synchronized(Global.lock) {
            //Do A stuff
        }
    }
}

public class JobB {
    public void go() {
        synchronized(Global.lock) {
            //Do B stuff
        }
    }
}
```

Problems with this:

1. We would queue up concurrent requests and not return an error message (which we want to do)
2. If `JobA` wants to write message to a queue to process asynchronously, how can we be assured that when the message is read from the queue by another method in `JobA` that the method will be able to acquire the `Global.lock` lock before another instance of `JobA` starts?

Any suggestions on a better approach?

Comment: It might make it easier to understand if you explain what A. B. and C actually do.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sounds like what you need is an exclusive lock where you can avoid blocking when trying to acquire the lock.

Fortunately the Lock interface has a tryLock method so you can do the following.

```
final Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();

....

void attemptJob( Runnable runnable )
{
    if (!lock.tryLock())
        throw new ConcurrentJobException();

    try
    {
       runnable.run();
    }
    finally
    {
       lock.unlock();
    }
}
```

If you want to run async then you should delegate the Runnable (or Callable if you prefer) to an ExecutorService and, when it completes, release the lock.

EDIT: e.g. (plus some more final declarations)

```
final Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();
final ExecutorService service = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

....

void attemptJob( final Runnable runnable )
{
    if (!lock.tryLock())
        throw new ConcurrentJobException();

    service.execute( new Runnable()
    {
        public void run()
        {
            try
            {
                runnable.run();
            }
            finally
            {
                lock.unlock();
            } 
        }
    });
}
```

Don't forget to shutdown() the ExecutorService when you are done with it.

Comment: Thanks. Could you provide more details on async using `ExecutorService`?

Answer (score 8):

Have you considered using a [SingleThreadExecutor](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newSingleThreadExecutor%28%29) ? As its name suggests, it uses a single thread to execute [Callables](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html) (similar to Runnables - see the doc) and thus satisfies your requirement for synchronous processing. Using the `java.util.concurrent` classes available will simplify your threading code enormously.

To handle the scenario when submitting a job when another job is running, and generating an error, set a bounded queue and a rejection handler. See [this page](http://book.javanb.com/java-concurrency-in-Practice/ch08lev1sec3.html) and section 8.3.2/8.3.3 specifically for details on [ThreadPoolExecutor.setRejectedExecutionHandler()](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html#setRejectedExecutionHandler%28java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionHandler%29).

Comment: Using SingleThreadExecutor doesn't satisfy the requirement for an error when job is submitted while another is still running.  It will just block and execute when the first job finishes.

Comment: Then used a bounded queue with max length 1 and configured to throw an exception rather than block.

Comment: Maybe you could use a ThreadPoolExecutor, with corePoolSize=1, maximumPoolSize=1 and workQueue=new ArrayBlockingQueue(1).

Comment: Specifically, set the rejection policy to `AbortPolicy` (http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.AbortPolicy.html)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Spring Batch](http://static.springsource.org/spring-batch/).  I think it can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is to use a configured ThreadPoolExecutor.  I **believe** this will work but strongly encourage readers to test it for themselves.

```
Executor executor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(1, 1,
                                    0L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS,
                                    new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>());
```

The above is approx what newSingleThreadExecutor does in the Executors class.

To satisfy the "error on concurrent task" requirement I think you can just change the queue implementation to a SynchronousQueue.

```
Executor executor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(1, 1,
                                    0L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS,
                                    new SynchronousQueue<Runnable>());
```

This should allow one task to run and if a second if submitted before the first finishes the ThreadPoolExecutor RejectedExecutionHandler will get called, which by default throws a RejectedExecutionException.