# How to wait till a POST request is completed in REST API?

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, web-services, rest

I wrote following methods to create a `REST API`. There is an example ,

**Example_bean.java**

```
public class Example_bean
{
    private int idAdress;
    private int idPatientt;
    private String addressType;
    private String line1;
    private String line2;
    private String city;
    private String state;
    private String zipCode;
    private String country;
    private Timestamp dateCreated;
    private Timestamp lastUpdated;

    /**
     * @return the idAdress
     */
    public int getIdAdress()
    {
        return idAdress;
    }

    /**
     * @param idAdress the idAdress to set
     */
    public void setIdAdress(int idAdress)
    {
        this.idAdress = idAdress;
    }

    /**
     * @return the idPatientt
     */
    public int getIdPatientt()
    {
        return idPatientt;
    }

    /**
     * @param idPatientt the idPatientt to set
     */
    public void setIdPatientt(int idPatientt)
    {
        this.idPatientt = idPatientt;
    }

    /**
     * @return the addressType
     */
    public String getAddressType()
    {
        return addressType;
    }

    /**
     * @param addressType the addressType to set
     */
    public void setAddressType(String addressType)
    {
        this.addressType = addressType;
    }

    /**
     * @return the line1
     */
    public String getLine1()
    {
        return line1;
    }

    /**
     * @param line1 the line1 to set
     */
    public void setLine1(String line1)
    {
        this.line1 = line1;
    }

    /**
     * @return the line2
     */
    public String getLine2()
    {
        return line2;
    }

    /**
     * @param line2 the line2 to set
     */
    public void setLine2(String line2)
    {
        this.line2 = line2;
    }

    /**
     * @return the city
     */
    public String getCity()
    {
        return city;
    }

    /**
     * @param city the city to set
     */
    public void setCity(String city)
    {
        this.city = city;
    }

    /**
     * @return the state
     */
    public String getState()
    {
        return state;
    }

    /**
     * @param state the state to set
     */
    public void setState(String state)
    {
        this.state = state;
    }

    /**
     * @return the zipCode
     */
    public String getZipCode()
    {
        return zipCode;
    }

    /**
     * @param zipCode the zipCode to set
     */
    public void setZipCode(String zipCode)
    {
        this.zipCode = zipCode;
    }

    /**
     * @return the country
     */
    public String getCountry()
    {
        return country;
    }

    /**
     * @param country the country to set
     */
    public void setCountry(String country)
    {
        this.country = country;
    }

    /**
     * @return the dateCreated
     */
    public Timestamp getDateCreated()
    {
        return dateCreated;
    }

    /**
     * @param dateCreated the dateCreated to set
     */
    public void setDateCreated(Timestamp dateCreated)
    {
        this.dateCreated = dateCreated;
    }

    /**
     * @return the lastUpdated
     */
    public Timestamp getLastUpdated()
    {
        return lastUpdated;
    }

    /**
     * @param lastUpdated the lastUpdated to set
     */
    public void setLastUpdated(Timestamp lastUpdated)
    {
        this.lastUpdated = lastUpdated;
    }
}
```

**Example_table.java**

```
    public class Example_table
{

    public String insertExample(int idPatient, String addressType, String line1, String line2, String city, String state, String zipCode, String country, Timestamp dateCreated, Timestamp lastUpdated)
    {
        String result = "";
        PreparedStatement ps = null;
        Connection con = null;

        String sql = "INSERT INTO `Example`(idPatient,AddressType,Line1,Line2,City,State,ZipCode,Country,DateCreated,LastUpdated) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";

        try
        {
            con = DBMaster.getInstance().getConnection();
            con.setAutoCommit(false);
            ps = con.prepareStatement(sql.toLowerCase());

            ps.setInt(1, idPatient);
            ps.setString(2, addressType);
            ps.setString(3, line1);
            ps.setString(4, line2);
            ps.setString(5, city);
            ps.setString(6, state);
            ps.setString(7, zipCode);
            ps.setString(8, country);
            ps.setTimestamp(9, dateCreated);
            ps.setTimestamp(10, lastUpdated);

            int executeUpdate = ps.executeUpdate();
            con.commit();

            if (executeUpdate > 0)
            {
                result = Common.SAVE_SUCCESS;
            } else
            {
                result = Common.SAVE_ROLLBACK;
            }

        } catch (Exception ex)
        {
            try
            {
                con.rollback();
                ex.printStackTrace();
                result = Common.SAVE_ROLLBACK;
            } catch (SQLException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } finally
        {
            try
            {
                if (ps != null)
                {
                    ps.close();
                }

                if (con != null)
                {
                    con.close();
                }

            } catch (SQLException ex)
            {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return result;
    }

    public String editExample(String addressType, String line1, String line2, String city, String state, String zipCode, String country, Timestamp dateCreated, Timestamp lastUpdated, int idAddress)
    {
        String result = "";
        PreparedStatement ps = null;
        Connection con = null;

        String sql = "UPDATE Example SET AddressType=?,Line1=?,Line2=?,City=?,State=?,ZipCode=?,Country=?,DateCreated=?,LastUpdated=? WHERE idAddress=?";

        try
        {
            con = DBMaster.getInstance().getConnection();
            con.setAutoCommit(false);

            ps = con.prepareStatement(sql.toLowerCase());

            ps.setString(1, addressType);
            ps.setString(2, line1);
            ps.setString(3, line2);
            ps.setString(4, city);
            ps.setString(5, state);
            ps.setString(6, zipCode);
            ps.setString(7, country);
            ps.setTimestamp(8, dateCreated);
            ps.setTimestamp(9, lastUpdated);
            ps.setInt(10, idAddress);

            int executeUpdate = ps.executeUpdate();
            con.commit();

            if (executeUpdate > 0)
            {
                result = Common.SAVE_SUCCESS;
            } else
            {
                result = Common.SAVE_ROLLBACK;
            }

        } catch (Exception ex)
        {
            try
            {
                con.rollback();
                ex.printStackTrace();
                result = Common.SAVE_ROLLBACK;
            } catch (SQLException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } finally
        {
            try
            {
                if (ps != null)
                {
                    ps.close();
                }

                if (con != null)
                {
                    con.close();
                }

            } catch (SQLException ex)
            {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return result;
    }

    public Example_bean getExample(int idAddress)
    {
        PreparedStatement ps = null;
        Connection con = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;

        Example_bean address_bean = new Example_bean();

        String sql = "SELECT * FROM Example WHERE idAddress=?";

        try
        {
            con = DBMaster.getInstance().getConnection();
            ps = con.prepareStatement(sql.toLowerCase());

            ps.setInt(1, idAddress);

            rs = ps.executeQuery();

            if (rs.isBeforeFirst())
            {

                while (rs.next())
                {

                    address_bean.setIdAdress(rs.getInt("idAddress"));
                    address_bean.setIdPatientt(rs.getInt("idPatient"));
                    address_bean.setAddressType(rs.getString("AddressType"));
                    address_bean.setLine1(rs.getString("Line1"));
                    address_bean.setLine2(rs.getString("Line2"));
                    address_bean.setCity(rs.getString("City"));
                    address_bean.setState(rs.getString("State"));
                    address_bean.setZipCode(rs.getString("ZipCode"));
                    address_bean.setCountry(rs.getString("Country"));
                    address_bean.setDateCreated(rs.getTimestamp("DateCreated"));
                    address_bean.setLastUpdated(rs.getTimestamp("LastUpdated"));

                }

            }

        } catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } finally
        {
            try
            {
                if (rs != null)
                {
                    rs.close();
                }
                if (ps != null)
                {
                    ps.close();
                }
                if (con != null)
                {
                    con.close();
                }
            } catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return address_bean;
    }

    public void syncExample(List<Address_bean> beanList)
    {
        PreparedStatement ps = null;
        Connection con = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;

        try
        {
            con = DBMaster.getInstance().getConnection();
            for (int i = 0; i < beanList.size(); i++)
            {
                String sql = "SELECT * FROM Example WHERE idAddress=? AND DateCreated=?";

                ps = con.prepareStatement(sql.toLowerCase());

                Example_bean address_bean = beanList.get(i);

                ps.setInt(1, address_bean.getIdAdress());
                ps.setTimestamp(2, address_bean.getDateCreated());

                rs = ps.executeQuery();

                if (rs.isBeforeFirst())
                {

                    while (rs.next())
                    {
                        System.out.println("There are  records");
                        editAddress(address_bean.getAddressType(), address_bean.getLine1(), address_bean.getLine2(), address_bean.getCity(), address_bean.getState(),
                                address_bean.getZipCode(), address_bean.getCountry(), address_bean.getDateCreated(), address_bean.getLastUpdated(), address_bean.getIdAdress());
                    }

                } else
                {
                    System.out.println("There are no records");
                    insertAddress(address_bean.getIdPatientt(), address_bean.getAddressType(), address_bean.getLine1(), address_bean.getLine2(), address_bean.getCity(), address_bean.getState(),
                            address_bean.getZipCode(), address_bean.getCountry(), address_bean.getDateCreated(), address_bean.getLastUpdated());
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } finally
        {
            try
            {
                if (rs != null)
                {
                    rs.close();
                }
                if (ps != null)
                {
                    ps.close();
                }
                if (con != null)
                {
                    con.close();
                }
            } catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**ExampleJSONService.java**

```
import java.util.List;
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;


@Path("/example")
public class ExampleJSONService
{
    @POST
    @Path("/syncExample")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public String syncExample(List<Example_bean> beanList)
    {
        System.out.println("Executed Bean List");

        for (int i = 0; i < beanList.size(); i++)
        {
            System.out.println("Inside REST: " + beanList.get(i).getLine1());
        }

        Example_table address_table=new Example_table();
        address_table.syncExample(beanList);
        return "";

    }
}
```

**TestClass.java**

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{

    try
        {

            Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
            WebTarget target = client.target("http://localhost:8080/DuctorEHR_REST/rest/example").path("/syncExample");

            Example_table address_table=new Address_table();
            Example_bean address_bean = address_table.getExample(341);
            address_bean.setLine1("Piliyandala Road");
            address_bean.setDateCreated(Common.getSQLCurrentTimeStamp());
            address_bean.setLastUpdated(Common.getSQLCurrentTimeStamp());

            List<Example_bean> address_beans=new ArrayList<Example_bean>();
            address_beans.add(address_bean);

        target.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE)
                    .post(Entity.entity(address_beans, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE));   


    } catch (Exception e)
    {
         e.printStackTrace();

    }

}
```

When I run this `TestClass.java`, It moves to the `synacExample()` method in the `ExampleJSONService` class . The method returns string it could be a error message or success message.

The `TestClass.java` will execute lot of methods similar to this, but it has to be one by one. For an example, `syncExample` process should be completed and should return the success/error message before it moves to the process of `syncExample2` (`syncExample2` is not mentioned in the code, but `TestClass.java` will execute a lot like this). How to do these processes one after another?

Any Ideas ? Thank you .

Comment: So while the request is being handled by the ExampleJSONService.syncExample method  you want to stop other methods from executing ? I am not sure i understand this correctly. Like what methods ?

Comment: @SomBhattacharyya :- While this method is executing , program should not execute another methods . As I told , I have more JSONServices classes like above . Basic is , Program cannot run another methods until this syncExample() method returns a value .

Comment: I dont think Any REST API should be designed in a way that their state matters. Basically each API should be idempotent. But there are ways to implement what you are saying. See here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1777542/how-to-prevent-concurrency-in-web-service-api

Comment: @SomBhattacharyya: Questiopn edited with more clear details. please have am look

Comment: Acquire a lock like the one mentioned in the link i posted and it will work.